# Object is not a member of package akka

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, akka, actor

trying to do my first steps with Scala, sbt and akka.

I'd like to import the akka.actor_ package to my script.

My build.sbt looks like this:

```
name := "hello"

version :="1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.3"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.4"
```

Stacktrace:
[image]

Any idea or hint on how to avoid this error and correctly import the needed package?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small typo in your import statement. It should be:

```
import akka.actor._
```

Notice the dot between `actor` and `_`.

Also, I don't know whether this is another typo, but you should use the latest version, 2.5.4, instead of 2.4.4.

Comment: If they weren't in your file, you wouldn't get them in the error message.

Comment: I use the eclipse plugin for sbt and I guess something went wrong with my \0.13\plugins.sbt. It finally works. Thanks for your help